# Data Set request: Blood donation data

Tags: data-request, medical

Does anyone know where I can find a dataset on blood donations in a given country or area with demographic information like household income ect.?

(Edited to be in line with the sites policy on data requests.)

**Context:** I'm doing research on whether paying donors for their blood donations or giving them a tax receipt is an incentive to donate more blood. I'm also trying to Identify if there is a reservation wage for blood donation

**Region:** Preferably either American or Canadian data but I will take anything that meets the other requirements.

**License:** Open available data or some other data set

**Format:** Whatever I can read into R. I usually use CSV file formats.

**Authority:** Im not picky, but please note the origin of the data

**Non-answers:** https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Blood+Transfusion+Service+Center (does not have info about income or consumption any goods and services)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are data on blood donors confined to specific regions and times. You could use these data to link with additional demographic information from other sources to indirectly infer the answer to your research goal.

A few examples:

- [Demographic characteristics of 1,783 blood donors from Taiwan](https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0048139.t001) (includes information on gender, age, occupation and educational level)
- [Demographic characteristics of blood donors at Debre Berhan blood bank, Central North Ethiopia, March 2014-June 2017](https://figshare.com/articles/dataset/Demographic_characteristics_of_blood_donors_at_Debre_Berhan_blood_bank_Central_North_Ethiopia_March_2014-June_2017_/6028184) (includes data on occupation, age and sex)
- [Members of the Italian Association of Voluntary Blood Donors](https://www.avis.it/it/statistiche) (by, partly economically disparate, regions)

You could browse through *Google Datasets* search results for the query `blood donors` (or so) to potentially find some more relevant data.